# my if statement in expect is not working

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm in the process of changing the password of an account for about 400 servers. When I ssh into the server, two possible prompts may appear: if the account has been expired, it will indicated:

```
Password:
Warning: Your password has expired, please change it now.
New Password:
```

Or I'll get the a normal prompt.

```
-bash-4.4$
```

So I want to write an expect script so that if I get the normal bash prompt, my script will proceed into changing the password or if the account has expired, it will proceed and change the password as well. My if statement in my script is erroring out.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "[DEBUG] INIT BASH"

CURRENT_PW="xxxxx"

NEW_PW="xxxxxx"

/opt/csw/bin/expect <(cat << EOF
spawn   ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no useradmin@xxxxx
expect "Password:"
send "$CURRENT_PW\r"

set PROMPT [ expect "New Password: "]

if { $PROMPT } {

send "$NEW_PW\r"
expect "Re-enter new Password: "
send "$NEW_PW\r"
exit

}
else

expect "$ "
send "passwd useradmin\r"
expect "New Password: "
send "$NEW_PW\r"
expect "Re-enter new Password: "
send "$NEW_PW\r"
expect "passwd: password successfully changed for useradmin"
send "exit\r"
interact
EOF
)

 echo "[DEBUG] END BASH"
```

Here is the error.

```
Password:
Warning: Your password has expired, please change it now.
New Password: empty expression
in expression "  "
(parsing expression "  ")
invoked from within
"if {  } {

send "xxxxxx\r"
expect "Re-enter new Password: "
send "xxxxxx\r"
exit

}"
(file "/dev/fd/63" line 7)
[DEBUG] END BASH
```

Comment: The problem is, that bash will replace `$PROMPT` for you, so tcl will only see the `if { } {...`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a use for expecting multiple things at once (and is indeed the banner case for it), which searches for two (or more) different strings and branches according to which one occurs first:

```
# Set up some obvious variables up here, of course...

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${User}@${Host}
expect "Password:"
send ${CurrentPassword}\r

# This waits for *either* the instruction to change the password or the main prompt
expect {
    "New Password: " {
        # A password change has been forced during login
        send ${NewPassword}\r
        expect "Re-enter new Password: "
        send ${NewPassword}\r
        expect "$ "
    }
    "$ " {
        # Initiate the password change
        send "passwd ${User}\r"
        expect "New Password: "
        send ${NewPassword}\r
        expect "Re-enter new Password: "
        send ${NewPassword}\r
        expect "passwd: password successfully changed for ${User}"
    }
}
send "exit\r"
close
exit
```

In this case we're not using `exp_continue`, which when used in the body script of an `expect` causes the waiting for a string to be restarted. That's useful for those cases where you can *optionally* hit something when logging in (and means that `expect` is able to work as sort of `while` as well as a sort of `if`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the value of `PROMPT` is the empty string.

You also have a problem with the formatting of the `if` invocation: you can't have an unescaped newline between `}` and `else`, and you need a `{` after `else` to enclose the alternate script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for a non-empty password, you should use something like

```
if {$PASSWORD ne ""} {
    ...
}
```

or

```
if {![string equal $PASSWORD ""]} {
    ...
}
```

Comment: On the same page: You would not recommend `[string equal]` over `eq` (`![string equal]` over `ne`) anymore, because in this context (if), `eq` and `ne` will benefit from optimisations (in the `expr` sublanguage), but also the Tcl bytecode IL.

Comment: @mrcalvin It does not matter. Both methods create (near) identical bytecode.